# My rails 3 applicaiton has to have a subdomain to work, my rspec controller test are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using lvh.me:3000 which redirects to localhost, and allows me to have wildcards like:

test.lvh.me:3000

In my application_controller, I make sure there is a subdomain in the url, and looking the subdomain in the database also.

If there is no subdomain, I redirect to an error page.

Because of this, my rspec controller tests are failing because the tests don't have a subdomain.

How can I make the `get 'index'` calls to use a subdomain that I know exists in the test db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get around this I do the following:

```
# spec/support/spec_helper_methods.rb
def require_subdomain
  @subdomain = # however you establish subdomains in you app
  controller.expects(:current_subdomain).returns(@subdomain)
  @request.host = "#{@subdomain}.test.host"
end
```

and then in my specs:

```
describe UsersController do

  describe "GET /users/new" do

    before do
      require_subdomain
    end

  end

end
```

Note - I'm using Mocha here, hence the `expects()` and `returns()` methods.

In my controller, I ask for `current_subdomain()` and raise a 404 if there isn't one

Comment: could this be done w/o mocha? i'm using rspec and factory_girl right now.